# How to add property to UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, quartz-core

thanks for all help:)! fixed it using iboutlet collection and add properies on viewDidLoad

I'm trying to add properties to keyboard keys like `layer.shadowColor` or `layer.shadowRadius`.
I got an error

```
 'Value of type '(UIButton)' -> () has no member 'layer'
```

how to fix this ?

this is my code keyboardViewController.swift

import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    var newKeyboardView: UIView!

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(sender: UIButton) {

}

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadInterface()

}

func loadInterface() {
    // load the nib file
    let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "newKeyboard", bundle: nil)
    // instantiate the view
    newKeyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    // add the interface to the main view
    view.addSubview(newKeyboardView)

    // copy the background color
    view.backgroundColor = newKeyboardView.backgroundColor
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
        textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @IBAction func keyPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        
    } i add some buttons and wanna add shadows to buttons. like using layer.shadowColor

Comment: Inside keyPressed(sender: UIButton) , write codes for adding shadows, for example i have added some codes for adding border color..     sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
sender.layer.borderWidth = 2.0                                                                               hope it helps.

Comment: got errors. it is same with i got last time :c.... ' btw thanks!

Comment: Try to type 'let button = sender as Button!' and 'button.layer.....' inside func keyPressed(sender: UIButton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in order to apply some style to the button, you need an outlet to this button.
Right now, from what I can understand, you are trying to apply styles to the button from the @IBAction to the sender, which is not the proper way to do it. 
Try to make an outlet to the button in the view controller and then to apply the styles from within the viewDidLoad method.

I hope this is clear, but if you want a more specific answer you need to show us what you tried, for example pasting the code you have in the view controller

**EDIT:** 
Based on the code you post, the keyboard is a Nib you instantiate from loadInterface(). I don't have a clear vision of the whole thing with only this piece of code, but it seems to me that you are trying to apply some styles to every key button of a keyboard view. Unfortunately this really depends on how the keyboard is implemented, can you provide some more details?

Anyway, from what I see I think you didn't write this code: probably you are following a tutorial or maintaining someone else's code. That's ok, but I suggest you to follow a an introduction course to iOS development with Swift, like the Udacity's one, which is fantastic IMHO (https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-ios-app-development-with-swift--ud585)

Comment: i'm confused . do you mean keyboardviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to "add property" not to a button, but rather to a closure which accepts a button as an argument.

Make it like this:

```
nextKeyboardButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor.cgColor
nextKeyboardButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
```

Comment: hmm i added button :o .. is there a way to add properties to uibutton?

Comment: @IBAction func keyPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
this is all about button that i wanna add something for :c ...

Comment: This is not the relevant code. Show the code where you're trying to set layer.shadowColor

Comment: i think my problem is that i'm trying to add things to button which is a IBAction not a IBOutlet ;-; i tried to set layer.shadowColor inside of IBAction func keypressed. it is not correct right ?

Comment: all you need is just show your code. I can't tell you without seeing

Comment: it is funny))) why don't you show the code where you're trying to set  layer.shadowColor and layer.shadowRadius ? that's all I need from you. I need to see what exactly you're trying to set shadowColor and shadowRadius to. do you understand?

Comment: i added inside of keyPressed func 'self.keyPressed.layer.shadowColor' but it didn't work so delete it :e no reason to leave it ;-;

Comment: @YuminHwang that's it. My original answer is correct. You're trying to set the properties to the function not the button. See my updated answer

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Ahh.. nextKeyboardbutton is not a button i'm using. it is a default button, even i didn't create :c ......

Comment: @YuminHwang so add the properties to the button that you're using)))

Comment: @YuminHwang I don't understand what is "default button". Where is it? You need to have a reference to it

Comment: i mean next keyboard button is the one which is created automatically when i created keyboardViewController.swfit. ibaction button is the button i wanna use

Comment: ibaction is NOT a button. it is a function. you see func next to it? IBAction is an action which happens when a button is tapped. You need to create a button and set the action to it

Answer (score 1):

If you try to format your UIButton with QuartzCore framework, you'll need to import it first:

```
import QuartzCore
```

Then you will be able to access those members.

For example (latest swift3 code):

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let button = sender as UIButton!
        button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button?.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        button?.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
}
```

In case you need to apply your styles sooner, try to consider to put this code into **viewDidLoad** or **viewDidAppear** methods:

```
    self.nextKeyboardButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.nextKeyboardButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.nextKeyboardButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    self.nextKeyboardButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
```

Comment: Anyway I can't imagine how it will look like, but the code should work like this :)